# I am getting Attribute error in fullmatch() while extract() is working fine

Tags: python, pandas

I am using pandas Series.str.extract(pattern) and Series.str.fullmatch(pattern) for checking if values in series are existing in pattern or not.
Extract() is working fine, however fullmatch() is giving me AttributeError.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'col1': ['aa', 'aabc', 'ee']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

pat_data = {'name': ['aa', 'bb', 'cc']}
df_p = pd.DataFrame(pat_data)
print(df_p)

pat = "|".join(map(str,df_p['name']))
print(pat)

# This one works fine 
df['col1'].str.extract('(' + pat + ')', expand=False)

# This one gives attribute error
df['col1'].str.fullmatch('(' + pat + ')')
```

### Output:
col1
0    aa
1  aabc
2    ee
name
0   aa
1   bb
2   cc
aa|bb|cc

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-e220391b2576> in <module>()
     16 
     17 # This one gives attribute error
---> 18 df['col1'].str.fullmatch('(' + pat + ')')

AttributeError: 'StringMethods' object has no attribute 'fullmatch'
```

Comment: share sample data

Comment: @qaiser I have updated and provided sample code to test.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this question is to use Regex in extract function for exact match pattern.

```
pat_data = {'name': ['^aa$', 'bb', 'cc']}
df_p = pd.DataFrame(pat_data) 
print(df_p)
```

Adding the start and end string regex in pattern will make it look for exact string in same code without any other workaround.